# Unable to install ubuntu 18.04 Desktop on surface 3 - sd card

Tags: sd-card, surface

There was a problem trying to configure multiboot by installing Ubuntu 18.04 on the Surface 3(not pro) - sd card

1. After installing Ubuntu on the sd card, booting will not proceed and will go to grub> screen.
2. As boot using ubuntu live usb, I get an error stating that the sd card is not capable of CRC error(I/O read).

However, I found that the sd card used for Ubuntu installation has no problem through check disk and bad sector check on Windows. I wonder what caused this problem.

=============================

[Symptoms - Surface use]

1. Boot to Ubuntu with live usb
2. Insert the sd card (Samsung 64gb pro sdxc u3) into the sd card slot
3. If check partition information with fdisk, do not respond in the order that the sd card comes out.
4. If check partition information with gparted, it will not respond after execution (only the gauge bar for partition search moves indefinitely)
5. If the sd card is connected via usb reader, the partition information is confirmed in fdiks and gparted
6. If insert another sd card (kingston 2gb) into the sd card slot, the partition information is found in fdisk and gparted
7. Boot to Windows 10 installed after shutdowning ubuntu
8. Normal operation about partition is done after inserting sd card (Samsung)

[Symptoms - Lenovo Notebook use]

1. Boot to Ubuntu with live usb
2. Insert the sd card (Samsung 64gb pro sdxc u3) into the sd card slot
3. the partition information is confirmed in fdiks and gparted

How can I fix/debug this?

[image]